# Why this constant declaration isn't working in Java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm having problems to declare constants as public, after searching a while in some books, I created this very simple program:

```
package course1;

public class Circle 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        public static final double QUARTER_VALUE = 0.25;
        System.out.println(QUARTER_VALUE);
    }
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Illegal modifier for parameter QUARTER_VALUE; only final is permitted

    at course1.Circle.main(Circle.java:7)
```

The problem is in this line:

```
public static final double QUARTER_VALUE = 0.25;
```

I was given the following message when I hover this line:

```
illegal modifier for parameter QUARTER_VALUE; only final is permitted
```

I don't understand why, following my books this should work.

Comment: `public static` doesn't make sense in that context. Did you want to declare it outside of `main` maybe?

Comment: Note the sentence in the duplicated question: constants go "to to the top" of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a method variable is only that method, so you do not need to specify the scope explicitly. A variable declared directly within a method is a local variable. A local variable cannot be declared as public. In fact, the only modifier that you can use on a local variable declaration is final

The access modifiers in case of variables are only applicable to class members and not method (local) variables.